# Angular 15: no ngModelGroupOptions for ngModelGroup in template driven forms?

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-ngmodel, formgroups

I am trying to implement template driven form with custom validations. In it, I want to validate the controls which are under my ngModelGroup on blur instead of triggering the validation as I type/change my inputs.

I can see we have *ngFormOptions*(for whole form level) and *ngModelOptions*(for control specific level), but there is no *ngModelGroupOptions*? We do have formGroupOptions support in Reactive Forms though:

```
  this.fb.group(
  {
    name: ["", [Validators.required]],
    email: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
  },
  { updateOn: "blur" }
);
```

Any reason why this support is not provided in template driven forms? Can someone please help on how can I specifically set my formGroup's updateOn without setting it on whole form or individual controls in this case?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You have to choose or Template Driven forms (forms that use `[(ngModel)]` **OR** Reactive Forms (forms that use `formControl`, `formGroup` and `fomControlName`, and you use formBuilder or new FormGroup to create). Your'e talking about template driven form but your code is related to Reactive forms. NOTE: to create a custom validator in Template Driven forms you use a directive. take a look to the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-custom-validators-to-template-driven-forms)

Comment: If you're using Tempalte driven form, you don't create groups, only create an object with properties that are also object: e.g. `user={id:0,name:'user',address:{city:'city', states:'state}}` and use `<input [(ngModel)]="user.address.city">`